# Centrar un Form con HTML y CSS

Tags: html, css, formularios

Quiero centrar un `div` que contiene un `form`. Intenté hacerlo con `display:flex`, pero no funciona.
Adjunto el HTML:

```
<div class="formcontacto">
            <form id="form" class="form" align="center" action="https://formspree.io/f/xzbyyrvn" method="POST">

                <input align="center" type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre y Apellido" required>


                <input type="mail" name="_replyto" placeholder="E-MAIL" required>



                <textarea name="message" placeholder="Tu Mensaje" required></textarea>

                <!-- your other form fields go here -->
                <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
            </form>
</div>
```

Por otra parte, mi CSS es este:

```
body{
  font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', 'serif', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  font: 1,2rem;
  line-height: 1,3em;
  margin: 0;
  
}
.form{
  display: block;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 500px;
  
}
  .formcontacto{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Y se ve de esta manera:
[image: Como se ve la el formulario de contacto]

Cuando en realidad, quiero que este esté en el medio de la pantalla.

Muchas Gracias.

Como quedó después de aplicar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    .formcontacto{
  position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-49%, -49%);
}
```

Comment: Saludos, he intentado replicar tu código y no soy capaz (me aparece de forma totalmente distinta). Por favor, pásame el CSS de la clase "form". ¡Gracias!

Comment: Haz un [repro] en tu pregunta convirtiendo tu código en snippet, pulsando en el botón que indica `<>`.

Comment: saca el `display: block;` del `.form` con eso ya te estaría funcionando con `flexbox`.

Comment: No funciona de esa forma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con este codigo, tu formulario de contacto debería centrarse completamente al centro de tu pantalla.

```
.formcontacto{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-49%, -49%);
}
```

En este caso, el contenido queda alineado completamente al centro de la pantalla, en caso de querer aumentar la altura del contenido para que el formulario se encuentre más abajo hay que añadir porcentaje a `top`. En caso inverso, querer que se encuentra más hacia arriba, decrementar porcentaje a `top`, los mismo para `left`.

Comment: El problema es que empieza a flotar en el medio de la pantalla y tapa el resto del contenido

Comment: Podrías insertar una imagen del problema que estas teniendo?

Comment: Listo, ya inserté una imagen

Comment: De acuerdo, ya veo tu problema, solo tienes que añadir mas porcentaje a `top: 50%`, piensa que lo que le estas diciendo es que tenga un espaciado de top de un 50%, si necesitas que tenga mas espaciado (que se vaya mas hacia abajo en este caso) añádele mas porcentaje, por ejemplo prueba con `top: 70%`, si necesitas mas, aumenta el valor. En caso de que quisieras que fuera más hacia arriba deberías decrementar el valor.

Comment: El código que te he publicado yo es para que este exactamente al centro de la pantalla como pedias. Hay otras formas de alinear al centro de la pantalla. Pero yo encuentro que esta es la forma más cómoda.

Comment: Listo. Muchísimas Gracias! Que tengas un buen día!

Answer (score 0):

Si alguien solo busca como centrar el Form en el centro del espacio que tiene predeterminado este codigo te servirá `form{ width:  50%; margin: 0 auto ; }`

es lo que yo estaba buscando pero esta encontré aquí para colocarlo en el centro de la pantalla, yo solo buscaba un efecto "text-align: center;", y este es :)